# Removing the highlight in a selected UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicontrol

A normal UIButton should look like this (I understand that button are supposed to have different colours from other text, but that this is a special case):

[image]

I wanted to use the `selected` property of a UIButton to determine whether it should be bold or not, and I already set the `.Selected` control state to have bold text with the following code:

```
let boldedOption = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
signInButton.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: "SIGN IN", attributes: boldedOption), forState: .Selected)
```

However, when I programmatically set the button's `selected` property to be true, this is the result:

[image]

What I originally want to achieve is for the button to have bolded text whenever the `selected` property of the UIButton is `true`, but in this case a border gets in the way, and the text is certainly not white as well.

Is there any way to dynamically bold the text of the UIButton based on user input with the `selected` property, or do I have to hack together another less elegant solution with a boolean?

Comment: better to use 2 images for different states .....

Comment: you need to change button type custom in Xib

Comment: Perhaps, but I would prefer to stick with text rather than creating 2 images for the 2 states

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the button type to Custom instead of System. This will take care of your blue background.

[image]